# How to handle manual invoked AWS lambda using serverless framework

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I am manually invoking my lambda function since the 30s HTTP gateway timeout is too short for my purpose. The function was working when using HTTP, but when I manually invoke the function, the `request.Body` is empty.

Here is the handler on my lambda code:

```
func handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) 
    (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    // Left out implementation details.
    // request.Body == "" here
}
```

Here is how I invoke it:

```
func InvokeHooknode(req *HooknodeReq) error {
    // Serialize params
    payload, err := json.Marshal(*req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Invoke lambda.
    client := lambda.New(sess)
    res, err := client.Invoke(&lambda.InvokeInput{
        FunctionName: aws.String(hooknodeFnName),
        Payload:      payload,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

I've printed out `payload`, and it looks correct. I'm just not sure how to access the payload in my lambda handler.

Answer (score 0):

Check the region that this function is in, and then check the region from which you are calling the function.

Instead of supplying the function name, insert the functions ARN as the function name.

```
Payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
```

instead of just

```
Payload: payload
```

Comment: The region looks right, and I am using the ARN as the function name. I have `hooknodeFnName` as a `const`.

Just to clarify, I am able to invoke the lambda. It just seems like the `payload` is not making it, and is blank.